# Unable to resolve POST call on redux observable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I am working on a react native application and on having a POST call with Observable.fromPromise, I am getting the below response, but I am not sure how to capture the response in terms of code and I amgetting some warnings as well

Response :

```
PromiseObservable {_isScalar: false, promise: Promise, scheduler: undefined}
promise: Promise
_40: 0
_55: Promise
_40: 0
_55: Promise
_40: 0
_51: 3
_55: Response
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: undefined
type: "default"
url: "http://localhost:9999/testPath/pathData"
_bodyBlob: Blob {_data: {…}}
_bodyInit: Blob {_data: {…}}
__proto__: Object
_65: 2
_72: null
__proto__: Object
_65: 3
_72: null
__proto__: Object
_65: 3
_72: null
__proto__: Object
scheduler: undefined
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Observable
```

Warning :

```
YellowBox.js:67 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Response {
  "_bodyBlob": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "D985543E-CD51-470C-91F9-3407AE59FDA1",
      "name": "test-data",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 0,
      "type": "application/json",
    },
  },
  "_bodyInit": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "D985543E-CD51-470C-91F9-3407AE59FDA1",
      "name": "test-data",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 0,
      "type": "application/json",
    },
  },
  "bodyUsed": true,
  "headers": Headers {
    "map": Object {
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "server": "Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)",
      "transfer-encoding": "Identity",
    },
  },
  "ok": true,
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": undefined,
  "type": "default",
  "url": "http://localhost:9999/testPath/pathData",
}
```

I am using mergeMap to capture the response, not sure why is it not working in this case

Code:

```
const testEpic: Epic<Action, ReduxState> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<any>,
  store: MiddlewareAPI<any, ReduxState>,
) =>
  action$
    .ofType(TEST_GET)
    .mergeMap((action) => {
      return Observable.merge(
          .fetch('/testPath/pathData', payload) // return part which is working properly
          .mergeMap((response) => {
             // calls not coming here for POST, PUT, DELETE even though it is status 200
          })
      )
    }
    )
    .catch((error) => {

    })
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @Rajan - Added the code, this code is generic and it is working everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it,actually it was going inside 'error' because of mismatch of contentType

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
fetch("/testPath/pathData", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Sitll the same error, it is not consolling anything